# Kafka command window

Tags: cmd, apache-zookeeper

Heey,
I am trying to get Kafka to work on Eclipse. So I´ve been installing it at the moment, but the problem is I am not too familiar with the cmd window. So I used some youtube tutorials and changed the necessary configurations of Kafka. The problem is in those tutorials they are typing in 2 paths behind each other for the file to be executed. But when I try that it says "The command "java" is either typed wrong or could not have been found". In all tutorials it works and the 2 commands I´ve been typing in work if I use them only one at a time, but the files are only being openend and not executed.

```
C:\Kafka\bin\windows>zookeeper-server-start.bat C:\Kafka\config\zookeeper.properties
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Eclipse to run Kafka unless you're trying to modify the source code for some reason.

Your error isn't with Kafka itself, but rather the fact that Kafka isn't really tested on Windows and the `.bat` files shouldn't really be ran.

Use WSL2 to run Kafka and Zookeeper with the `.sh` scripts, or use Docker on a Windows host